# transition and transform behavior works only for once 1st time

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have one simple HTML CSS page where I have 10 circles and when I hover on one circle it moves to right side of page and also displays the number written on it.everything is done by [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions) and [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) properties.

trasition works only for very 1st circle hover and only once ( even in codepen and SO inbuilt code panel behave differently) and after that, if we hover to next circle it keeps transforming but does not stay after a given interval.

it behaves sometimes only for even circle and sometimes for all.

what is the issue and how to fix?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
:root {
    --bg-color: #454678;
    --color__1: salmon;
    --color__2: lightskyblue;
    --color__3: khaki;
    --color__4: thistle;
    --color__5: mediumturquoise;
}

body {
    background-color: indianred;
}

.container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2em auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header"
        "main";
    grid-gap: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: safe left;
    align-content: center;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: main;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: start;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.circle {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color__3, khaki);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 10em;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--color__1);
}

.circle:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: scale(2) translateX(50em);
    background-color: var(--color__5, salmon);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <header>Press any Number</header>
        <main>
            <div class="circle">1</div>
            <div class="circle">2</div>
            <div class="circle">3</div>
            <div class="circle">4</div>
            <div class="circle">5</div>
            <div class="circle">6</div>
            <div class="circle">7</div>
            <div class="circle">8</div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Note: I am checking only with the latest chrome only.

Comment: are you aware that you are moving the element far from the mouse? you need to follow it in order to keep that state ..

Comment: I have set margin and padding for each circle so that each circle hover area doesn't get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the circle is not hovered after it gets moved to the right. A possible solution would be to put it in a container, that stretches with the circle and bind the hover event to that container, see below.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
:root {
    --bg-color: #454678;
    --color__1: salmon;
    --color__2: lightskyblue;
    --color__3: khaki;
    --color__4: thistle;
    --color__5: mediumturquoise;
}

body {
    background-color: indianred;
}

.container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2em auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header"
        "main";
    grid-gap: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: safe left;
    align-content: center;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: main;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: start;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.circle {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color__3, khaki);
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 10em;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--color__1);
}

.outer:hover .circle {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: scale(2) translateX(50em);
    background-color: var(--color__5, salmon);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <header>Press any Number</header>
        <main>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">1</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">2</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">3</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">4</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">5</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">6</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">7</div></div>
            <div class="outer"><div class="circle">8</div></div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: it works fine here in the code block but does not work for even number div in chrome.

Comment: Hmmm, I have copied it to a plain HTML file and everything works fine - even for the even numbers. Do you maybe have any other CSS rules that override some of the rules applied to even numbers?